# Jasmine Typeerror on innerHTML assignment

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing test cases for a project, many of the questions about this topic are angular and I can't seem to find a pure Javascript one.

HTML

```
<div class="js-export-calls">
    <button class="js-export-button">Export</button>
    <p class="js-export-progress hide"></p>
    <div class="gen-loader hide"></div>
</div>
<ul class="message {% if not errors %}hide{% endif %} js-error"></ul>
```

My Javascript looks like this:

```
_showError() {
     let error = this._window.document.querySelector('.js-error');
     error.innerHTML = 'An error has occurred';
}
```

My Jasmine test case:

```
describe('When _showError() is called', () => {
     let source;
        beforeEach(() => {
            source = "calls"
        });

      it('Should show default message to send error', () => {
            const response = 'Error occurred, please retry';
            item._showError(source, response);
            expect(item._showError).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

And I'm getting this error: *TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.*

But it goes away when I comment my innerHTML assignment on my JS. Is there something special I have to do? Or do I have to add something to my Jasmine?

Any help is appreciated as this is my second day trying to decipher it to no avail... And thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the HTML / entire solution.  It's possible the script is running before things are rendered.  Or there could be a safeguard against setting `innerHTML`, which can be dangerous.

Comment: I've added the html and unfortunately, the code is too big :(. I've posted the relevant pieces I think, but even then, it looks good to me, I don't know why it's failing.

Comment: Where is the script loaded that has the _showError function?